# Are there any change or new features about Terminal.app in High Sierra?

Tags: macos, terminal, high-sierra

Are there any change or new features with Terminal.app in High Sierra?

There is no leak about terminal, so I want to hear from user who already use High Sierra Beta.

I wish that apple support 24bit color rendering in terminal.